# Routing , RouteData empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to register 2 routes.

One on / and a second on /details/{username}

In my RouteConfig.cs I tried :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Details",
            url: "details/{username}",
            defaults: new { action = "Details", username = "" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controleur}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index"}
        ); 
}
```

and in my Details.aspx.cs I have:

```
public partial class _Details : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = RouteData.Values.Keys.Count;
    }
}
```

However I can't get the username value in RouteData.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you map routes for MVC-projects. You seem to be using Web Forms.
This is how to map routes for Web Forms:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Details", 
                    "details/{username}", 
                    "Details.aspx", 
                    false, 
                    new RouteValueDictionary {{"action", "Details"}, {"username", ""}});
```

Comment: the default route is generate by Visualstudio ... i juste try reproduct ...
I test your solution bug i have a exeption : VirtualPath must be a non-empty